# What are sufficient conditions for "homotopy equivalence" of slice contours?

Tags: homotopy-theory, surfaces

Apologies in advance for imprecision of the question. Thanks for improving it. Let M be a compact, connected, orientable surface in three dimensional Euclidean space without boundary and without self-intersections, such as a sphere, or a torus. Define a slice contour C of M to be the non-empty intersection of M with a plane. (For example, the equator of a sphere is a slice contour; there are different ways that a torus admits slice contours consisting of two disjoint circles.) Define two slice contours C and D to be equivalent if there exists a continuous homotopy H from the inclusion map of C into M to the inclusion map of D into M, such that the inclusion map at every stage of H is an injective homeomorphism. This is an equivalence relation on the set of all slice contours. What are sufficient conditions for the following statements to be jointly true: (1) a slice contour is a finite 1-dimensional CW complex; (2) there is a finite number of equivalence classes; (3) there exists at least two equivalence classes with exactly one member; (4) there exists at least one equivalence class
with a continuum of members.